# Lotus notes, edit one form from another

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

Basically what I want to do is create a form whilst within another form and pass values from the earlier form to the second. Complicated I know but here is what I got.

```
@Do(@Command([Compose];"LPK"); @SetField("PR_Make"; PR_Make))
```

The fields in both forms have the same name and this code is called when first document is attempted to be saved.
I think instead of editing the field on the second form it just saves a field as itself instead. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and common way is to enable form property "**Formulas inherit values from selected document**" in second form "LPK".

[image]

Add a default value formula to second form's fields you want to inherit and put just the name of field itself in. For your example default value formula it would be

```
PR_Make
```

Make sure you **save** document **first** and then create the new document.

Comment: I tried this method and it did not work unfortunately. Don't think it recognised it as the parent document for some reason.

Comment: You have to save document first.

Comment: I implemented a feature to save the document before the command to create the second document and this too did not solve my problem

Comment: It should work :) - does your code look like this: `@Command([FileSave]); @Command([Compose];"LPK");`? If not, please add your complete formula to your question.

Comment: The code saved within this is as follows. @If(Look *= PR_Full; ""; @If(@Prompt([YesNo]; "No such printer Exists"; "Printer does not exist, do you want to create an entry for this model of printer?" ) = 1;@Do(@Command([FileSave]); @Command([Compose];"LPK"); @SetField("PR_Make"; PR_Make))

Comment: You don't need @SetField anymore. Please double check property "Formulas inherit values ..." is set and Default Value formula for field "PR_Make" is `PR_Make`, both in form "**LPK**".

Comment: You might try `@PostedCommand([Compose];"LPK")`. This would create the new document for sure *after* current document is saved.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks a bunch. Works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Knut Hermann's answwer is the 'standard' way of achieving such things but there are other methods- eg you can use environment variables ..

Something like:

```
@Environment("PR_Make") := PR_Make;
@Command([Compose];"LPK");
```

Then set the default value for PR_Make in your new form as ..

```
@Environment("PR_Make")
```

FYI Environment variables are written to the user's Notes.ini file and so remain even after Notes has been closed and re-opened. @Environemt doens't work too well with Web applications as it uses the server's notes.ini.

An alternative would be to use profile documents:

```
@SetProfileField( "PRDefaults"; "PR_Make" ; PR_Make;@Username);
@Command([Compose];"LPK");
```

.. in the default field for PR_Make on new form :

```
@GetProfileField( "PRDefaults"; "PR_Make"; @Username);
```

Profile documents are stored as a kind of hidden document in the Notes database and persist with the database. The last parameter sets a further subdivision by username so each user gets their own profile doc - a bit like a personal profile for "PRDefaults". You can miss this last parameter @Username out, to have one profile doc per database but there's a risk of two people trying to use it at the same time and clashing.

Profile docs also work with web applications.